# How secure is Firestore if you let anyone read the data, but not write

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore

So essentially, I am trying to set up sign up, where a user needs a special secret key in order to sign up, and register. From my research firebase doesnt have any inbuild tools to accomplish this.

So here is my solution. I essentially have a collection called secret, and then within it have different documents, where the id of the document is the key. The security rules of this collection is allow read: true, allow write: false.

Now basically when the user presses signup after filling out the form, which contains email, password and secret key. This function runs

```
const handleSignUp = useCallback(async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const {email, password, secretkey} = event.target.elements;

    const usersRef = db.collection('secret').doc(secretkey.value)

    usersRef.get()
        .then(async (docSnapshot) => {
            if (docSnapshot.exists) {
                //console.log("true", docSnapshot.data())
                try {
                    const re = await app
                        .auth()
                        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value);



                } catch (error) {
                    alert(error);
                }

            } else {
                alert("Please enter a valid secret Key, or contact help@company.com  for further assistance")
            }
        });

});
```

So here is my question. How secure is the secret's collection, especially because the read permissions is set to true. My assumption is that it is secure, since my app is set so that it can only run on my domain only. Therefore even if someone has the firebase config keys, they cant read the secret collections data. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're allowing all reads, then a user can do a `get()` on the entire collection to get a list of all documents. They can use that to then read all documents, and the secret values in there.

The only way that I know of to secure this is to:

1. Make the actual secret value be the ID of the document.
2. Allow `get` access on the documents, but don't allow `list` on the collection.

   If you've never done this: `read` is shorthand for `list` + `get`. See the docs on [granular operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations).

Comment: This seems to work, with some testing I did. Is it safe to say that this is super secure?

Comment: Being secure is not a binary attribute. That's why I tried to explain the risk you have with your current approach, and what my answer changes about that. Whether that covers the risks you care about, only you can determine.

Answer (score 0):

Without [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) that determine [which authenticated users can read the data in the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query), anyone will be able to read the data, and it's not secure at all.

If you're not using Firebase Authentication, then it will be impossible to write security rules to restrict access to the collection from just your app.